# meta refresh for redirection not working in BlackBerry

Tags: redirect, blackberry, refresh, meta-tags

I asked this question [here](http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/223556-redirection-meta-refresh.html) but don't get reply so far. I hope posting it too here is ok.

For page redirection, in a mobile site development, I am using

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/pagetwo.jsp"/>
```

because it is required to work when Javascript is off.

However, I find it working only in BlackBerry (BB) simulator, not in real BB (I tried with BB 8250 and 9700).

Could anyone help me please, what could be the reason.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using meta for refreshing the browser isn't a good idea for a number of reasons (disables back-button, etc) and what's probably happening is your other blackberry has an accessibility issue where it won't let pages refresh themselves. Try setting it in the server-side HTTP response if you can

According to BlackBerry Browser documentation article ["HTML element: <meta>"](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11848/HTML_ref_meta_564143_11.jsp)  meta refresh isn't available until software version 3.7 or later.

Comment: Hi rkulla, thanks for your help. 

I will, first, try to find out that accessibility issue, which may exist in BB.